# NUnit testing a controller method that returns a list

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, nunit

I am writing a test for a controller method.This method accesses the `getPharmacySupply` method in `SupplyRepository` which return a list of `PharmacyMedicineSupply` according to the project requirement:

```
[HttpPost("PharmacySupply")]
public Task<List<PharmacyMedicineSupply>> GetPharmacySupply([FromBody] List<MedicineDemand> medDemand)
{
        _log4net.Info("Get Pharmacy Supply API Acessed");
        return _supplyRepo.GetPharmacySupply(medDemand);
}
```

These are my models:

```
public class MedicineStock
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ChemicalComposition  { get; set; }
    public string TargetAilment { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfExpiry { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfTabletsInStock { get; set; }
}

public class PharmacyMedicineSupply
{
    public string pharmacyName { get; set; }
    public List<MedicineNameAndSupply> medicineAndSupply { get; set; }
}

public class MedicineNameAndSupply
{
    public string medicineName { get; set; }
    public int supplyCount { get; set; }
}
```

This is the test I am writing:

```
public static List<MedicineDemand> mockMedicineDemand= new List<MedicineDemand>()
{
            new MedicineDemand()
            {
                Medicine = "Medcine1",
                DemandCount = 20
            },
            new MedicineDemand()
            {
                Medicine = "Medcine2",
                DemandCount = 25
            },
            new MedicineDemand()
            {
                Medicine = "Medcine3",
                DemandCount = 30
            },
            new MedicineDemand()
            {
                Medicine = "Medcine4",
                DemandCount = 35
            },
            new MedicineDemand()
            {
                Medicine = "Medcine5",
                DemandCount = 40
            }

[Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(mockMedicineDemand))]
public void Test_GetPharmacySupply(List<MedicineDemand> mockMedicineDemand)
{
        Mock<ISupplyRepo> supplyMock = new Mock<ISupplyRepo>();
        
        SupplyController sc = new SupplyController(supplyMock.Object);
        var result = sc.GetPharmacySupply(mockMedicineDemand) as Task<List<PharmacyMedicineSupply>>;
        var resultList = result.Result;
        Assert.That(4,Is.EqualTo( resultList[0].medicineAndSupply[0].supplyCount));
}
```

But I am getting this error

> Object of type 'MedicineSupplyMicroservice.Models.MedicineDemand' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MedicineSupplyMicroservice.Models.MedicineDemand]'.

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are testing, `GetPharmacySupply` takes a single argument, which is a `List` of `MedicineDemand` objects.

NUnit, on the other hand, is calling it with a *single* `MedicineDemand`.

Take a look at your data source declaration...

```cs
public static List<MedicineDemand> mockMedicineDemand= new List<MedicineDemand>()
{
   ...
}
```

The `TestCaseDataAttribute` designates a field, property or method, which returns the necessary data for *one or more* test cases. Your source is returning a `List<MedicineDemand>` so NUnit takes that list and uses the content to call your method five times, once for each `MedicineDemand`.

This is clearly an error and NUnit might be a bit smarter about it and mark your test as non-runnable. However, with the current versions of NUnit, it defers the check until your test is actually run. (Once you have used `TestCaseSource` a lot, the error message leads you right to the problem.)

So your data source, in this case, needs to be a list or other type of enumeration of `List<MedicineDemand>` - basically a list of lists.

One way to do that would be to use `List<List<MedicineDemand>>` but I think it would make the code more, rather than less, confusing!

There are a lot of options here - check the docs for `TestCaseSourceAttribute`. My personal preference would be to make the data source into a method, as follows:

```cs
    public static IEnumerable<List<MedicineDemand>> MockMedicineDemands()
    {
        yield return new List<MedicineDemand>
        {
            new MedicineDemand() { Medicine = "Medicine1", DemandCount = 20 },
            new MedicineDemand() { Medicine = "Medicine2", DemandCount = 25 },
            new MedicineDemand() { Medicine = "Medicine3", DemandCount = 30 },
            new MedicineDemand() { Medicine = "Medicine4", DemandCount = 35 },
            new MedicineDemand() { Medicine = "Medicine5", DemandCount = 40 }
        };

        // Add more cases here if desired
```

Additionally, I believe the code would be clearer, both to others and to yourself when you return to it after a period of time, if you named the lists differently from the individual components, that is something like`mockMedicineDemandList` or `mockMedicineDemands`.

Fair warning... it's not convenient for me to compile the above code right now, so it's just "forum code." Typos etc. are a strong possibility. Please post a comment if you find any errors.